# Can I write "equal author contribution" in acknowledgment?

Tags: journals, acknowledgement, proofreading

One of my papers is now in the proofreading stage. In the revision stage, I didn't add the "equal author contribution" as a foot-note. Is it possible to add that now? Can I put it in the acknowledgment section?

Note: I am not allowed to add any sign beside the authors' names.

Edit:
I was finally able to do that. During the proofreading, I mentioned this issue and they added a footnote. They were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer, I would consider that listing `equal contribution` in the acknowledgement section generally does not carry the weight as listing it as part of the front page. However, if it is clear that journal policy does not allow any mentioning of equal contributions on the title page, the acknowledgements may be your best options.

However, I think that you should have a clear discussion about this right away between the senior authors, the co-authors, and the editor. Co-authorship can have significant impact on the career of individuals, so you want to be certain that everybody is clear in what is going to happen and is in agreement with the path chosen.

Comment: I have the feeling that there is no standardized way to list (or parse) "equal contribution" annotations, so my feeling would be that it does not matter.  (Say, if you put the paper on your CV, you could/would mention this fact explicitly; and I'm not aware that indexing services take this into account.)

Comment: You may be right. But there needs to be clarity and certainty. Telling a potential joint-first author after the fact that this was the best option is not really a good way to approach this. You need to be certain about the options and need to clearly communicate these options to everybody to get their consent about moving ahead.

Comment: That was not my point. My point was relating to your "I would consider that listing equal contribution in the acknowledgement section generally does not carry the weight as listing it as part of the front page".  I meant to say: I don't see that there is a clear way how such a kind of "equal contribution" label is mapped to relevant information in relevant scenarios (CV, bibliometry, etc.), so - beyond someone actually reading the article - it does not matter so much.  (From the author point, not from the journal point!)  Where *would* it carry more weight?

Comment: (I notice you quite rewrote your comment while I was responding ... I guess we're more on the same side now - as I said: "Ask the editor.")

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for clarifying your point. And yes, I rewrote my comment because at first I assumed it was the OP who was commenting. I wanted to make sure pritom is certain on all options and clearly communicates them to all authors.

Answer (score 0):

Whether, and what, you can edit at this stage, and what kind of information is allowed in the acknowledgements, likely depends on the journal. You should contact the editor, since they will be able to tell you.  (And, needless to say, you need to have the permission of your co-authors to do this change.)

In fact, some journals (Nature comes to mind) even have an "Author contributions" field in which one can (or even has to) describe how the individual authors contributed.